# How to make sure the table doesn't break when spanning multiple pages

Tags: tables, longtable, multirow

I am trying to find a way to make sure that a long table doesn't break when spanning multiple pages.

I tried using long table with multirow but the page is splitting the table. By splitting I mean either the tabular `row2` at the end of the first page goes entirely to the next page or take it to the previous page. Is there anyway to have this incorporated here?

```
\usepackage{longtable}

\begin {longtable}{|p{1.0in}|p{1.0in}|m{1.10in}|m{1.25in}|}
\hline
col 1
& col 2
& col 3
& col 4
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 1}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 2}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 2}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 2}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 2}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 2}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 2}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{row 2}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
& foo2
& bar2
& yikes2
\\*\cline{2-4}
\\\hline
\end {longtable}
```

I am getting the results as indicated in the attached screenshots

[image]

[image]

Comment: `longtable` provides the commands `\\*` and `\nopagebreak` to avoid page breaks in unwanted places.  Consult the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Although this does not directly answer your question, here is nevertheless a suggestion/something to consider: I would avoid the combination of `\multirow` with `longtable` as it might not only lead to the multirow cell being split over two pages but could also cause the multirow text to overlap with the footer/ page number (See for example here: [longtable cut text overlapping with footnote](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/567511/134144)) I thus suggest the following redesign of the table in which the text you originally placed in multirow is now placed in a multicolumn to act like some kind of sub-header in the table. (See also this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/565576/134144 in which I applied a similar technique.)
With the use of `\\*` you can then prevent a pagebreak after between specific rows.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\null\vspace{9cm}
\begin {longtable}{@{\qquad}p{1.0in}p{1.10in}p{1.25in}}
\toprule
 col 2
& col 3
& col 4
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{row 1}\\*
 foo1
& bar1 bar1 bar1 bar1
& yikes1 yikes1 yikes1 yikes1 yikes1 yikes1 yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{row 2}\\*
 foo1
& bar1 
& yikes1 
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{row 3}\\*
 foo1
& bar1 
& yikes1 
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{3}{l}{row 4}\\*
 foo1
& bar1 
& yikes1 
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\*
 foo1
& bar1
& yikes1
\\
\midrule
\\\hline

\end {longtable}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution that I think will work here to insert the portion to the table where we want to split it.

```
\pagebreak
\hline
```

If there is some other way, please feel free to post in the answers.