# Column on longtable doesn't show up

Tags: longtable

I can't make some of the numbers on the PSS column to show up and other don't even show, can somebody help me?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{multirow,longtable, array, booktabs, makecell,rotating}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2206}{\ensuremath\delta}


\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cccp{21.145em}cccc}
  \caption{Add caption}
  \centering
    Dataset & kappa & Model & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Parameters} & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.5em}}{Likelihood\newline{}(lnL)} & 2∆lnL (LRT) & \multicolumn{1}{p{6.215em}}{Significance\newline{}(p-value)} & \multicolumn{1}{p{4.855em}}{PSS} \\
    \midrule
    \multirow{12}[1]{*}{\begin{sideways}Basal 40\end{sideways}} & \multirow{4}[1]{*}{0.2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p =   0.616 q = 0.374} & 4234.922 & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{4.121} & \multirow{2}[1]{*}{1.000} & \multirow{4}[1]{*}{-} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.994 p = 0.634 q = 0.421 \newline{}(p1 =   0.006) w = 2.742 & 4236.983 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.516 p = 32.811 q = 99.000\newline{}(p1 =   0.484) w = 1.000 & 4232.605 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{8.755} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{1.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.994 p = 0.634 q = 0.421 \newline{}(p1 =   0.006) w = 2.742 & 4236.983 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.642 q = 0.412} & 4235.016 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{6.681} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.035} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{-} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.748 p = 1.586 q = 2.192 \newline{}(p1 = 0.252) w = 1.475 & 4231.675 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.516 p = 32.811 q = 99.000  \newline{}(p1 =   0.4838) w = 1.000 & 4232.605 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{1.860} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.173} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.748 p = 1.586 q = 2.192 \newline{}(p1 = 0.252) w = 1.475 & 4231.675 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{5} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p =   0.548 q =  0.314} & 4235.293 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{5.375} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.068} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{-} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.859 p = 0.918 q = 0.804  \newline{}(p1 = 0.141) w = 1.701 & 4232.419 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.516 p = 32.811 q = 99.000 \newline{}(p1 = 0.484) w = 1.000 & 4232.605 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.372} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.542} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.859 p = 0.918 q = 0.804  \newline{}(p1 = 0.141) w = 1.701 & 4232.419 &       &       &  \\
    \multirow{12}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}Strisores Aequorlitornithes 40 \end{sideways}} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.651 q = 0.345} & 5150.191 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{43.958} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{231, 276} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.755 p = 77.686 q = 99.000\newline{}(p1 = 0.245) w = 1.968 & 5128.212 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.528 p = 37.626 q = 99.000  \newline{}(p1 =   0.472) w =   1.000 & 5141.065 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{25.706} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.755 p = 77.686 q = 99.000\newline{}(p1 = 0.245) w = 1.968 & 5128.212 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.651 q = 0.341} & 5147.952 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{34.978} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{48, 231, 276}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.851 p = 1.259 q = 0.934  \newline{}(p1 = 0.149) w = 2.375 & 5130.463 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.535 p = 39.756 q = 99.000  \newline{}(p1 = 0.465) w = 1.000 & 5141.103 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{21.279} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.851 p = 1.259 q = 0.934  \newline{}(p1 = 0.149) w = 2.375 & 5130.463 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{5} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.722 q = 0.415} & 5147.937 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{13.745} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.001} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{231, 276} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.831 p = 1.645 q = 1.435  \newline{}(p1 = 0.169) w = 2.193 & 5129.820 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.528 p = 37.626 q = 99.000  \newline{}(p1 = 0.472) w = 1.000 & 5141.065 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{22.491} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.831 p = 1.645 q = 1.435  \newline{}(p1 = 0.169) w = 2.193 & 5129.820 &       &       &  \\
    \multirow{12}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}Acanthisittidae Tyranni Passeri 40\end{sideways}} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.474 q = 0.321} & -9711.558 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{234.997} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.799 p = 0.561 q = 0.446  \newline{}(p1 = 0.201) w = 2.790 & -9594.059 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.507 p = 2.450 q = 11.117\newline{}(p1 = 0.494) w = 1.000 & -9688.670 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{189.221} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.799 p = 0.561 q = 0.446  \newline{}(p1 = 0.201) w = 2.790 & -9594.059 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.480 q = 0.319} & -9711.442 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{234.203} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{14, 33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.800 p = 0.550 q = 0.435  \newline{}(p1 = 0.200) w = 2.762 & -9594.340 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.507 p = 2.450 q = 11.120  \newline{}(p1 = 0.494) w = 1.000 & -9688.670 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{188.659} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.800 p = 0.550 q = 0.435  \newline{}(p1 = 0.200) w = 2.762 & -9594.340 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{5} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.187 q = 0.041} & -9713.369 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{237.519} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{14, 33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 113, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.811 p = 0.540 q = 0.444  \newline{}(p1 = 0.189) w = 2.768 & -9594.610 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.507 p = 2.450 q = 11.117 \newline{}(p1 = 0.494) w = 1.000 & -9688.670 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{188.120} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.811 p = 0.540 q = 0.444  \newline{}(p1 = 0.189) w = 2.768 & -9594.610 &       &       &  \\
    \multirow{12}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}Passeri 1 40\end{sideways}} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.421 q = 0.386} & -11405.799 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{256.626} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{6, 7, 20, 33,\newline{} 36, 40, 41, 43,\newline{} 46, 48, 49, 50, \newline{}52, 55, 56, 57, \newline{}59, 60, 61, 64,\newline{} 70, 112, 114, 125, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 151, 152, 158, 160, 161, 163, 164, 165, 180, 184, 188, 190, 205, 206, 220, 231, 232, 235, 238, 239, 242, 244, 245, 246, 252, 256, 266, 277, 279}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.745 p = 0.872 q = 1.130  \newline{}(p1 = 0.255) w = 2.364 & -11277.486 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.598 p = 2.219 q = 8.395\newline{}(p1 = 0.402) w = 1.000 & -11373.833 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{192.695} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.745 p = 0.872 q = 1.130  \newline{}(p1 = 0.255) w = 2.364 & -11277.486 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.469 q = 0.411} & -11405.085 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{253.680} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{ 6, 7, 20, 33, 36, 40, 41, 43, 46, 48, 49, 50, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 64, 70, 112, 114, 125, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 151, 152, 158, 160, 161, 163, 164, 165, 180, 184, 188, 190, 205, 206, 220, 231, 232, 235, 238, 239, 242, 244, 245, 246, 252, 256, 266, 277, 279}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.767 p = 0.860 q = 1.137  \newline{}(p1 = 0.233) w = 2.325 & -11278.245 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.598 p = 2.219 q = 8.395  \newline{}(p1 = 0.402) w = 1.000 & -11373.833 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{191.177} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.767 p = 0.860 q = 1.137  \newline{}(p1 = 0.233) w = 2.325 & -11278.245 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{5} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p =   0.437 q =   0.387} & -11405.189 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{62.711} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{6, 7, 20, 33, 36, 40, 41, 43, 46, 48, 49, 50, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 64, 70, 112, 114, 125, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 151, 152, 158, 160, 161, 163, 164, 165, 180, 184, 188, 190, 205, 206, 220, 231, 232, 235, 238, 239, 242, 244, 245, 246, 252, 256, 266, 277, 279}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.777 p = 0.839 q = 1.090  \newline{}(p1 = 0.223) w = 2.389 & -11278.856 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.598 p = 2.219 q = 8.395  \newline{}(p1 = 0.402) w = 1.000 & -11373.833 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{189.954} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.777 p = 0.839 q = 1.090  \newline{}(p1 = 0.223) w = 2.389 & -11278.856 &       &       &  \\
    \multirow{12}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}Passeri 2 40\end{sideways}} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.581 q = 0.493} & -15508.558 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{192.533} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{7, 11, 70, 117, 126, 128, 131, 154, 160, 165, 180, 188, 220, 235, 239, 266, 275, 279}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.920 p = 0.669 q = 0.610\newline{}(p1 = 0.080) w = 2.609 & -15412.292 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.667 p = 1.297 q = 3.397  \newline{}(p1 = 0.333) w = 1.000 & -15489.545 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{154.507} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.920 p = 0.669 q = 0.610\newline{}(p1 = 0.080) w = 2.609 & -15412.292 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.545 q = 0.489} & -15509.467 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{194.352} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{7, 11, 70, 117, 126, 128, 131, 154, 160, 165, 180, 188, 220, 235, 239, 266, 275, 279}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.920 p = 0.669 q = 0.610  \newline{}(p1 = 0.080) w = 2.609 & -15412.292 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.667 p = 1.297 q = 3.397  \newline{}(p1 = 0.333) w = 1.000 & -15489.545 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{154.507} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.920 p = 0.669 q = 0.610  \newline{}(p1 = 0.080) w = 2.609 & -15412.292 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{5} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.551 q = 0.465} & -15509.257 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{39.424} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{7, 11, 70, 117, 126, 128, 131, 154, 160, 165, 166, 180, 188, 220, 235, 239, 266, 275, 279}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.928 p = 0.698 q = 0.676  \newline{}(p1 = 0.072) w = 2.372 & -15415.125 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.667 p = 1.297 q = 3.396\newline{}(p1 = 0.333) w = 1.000 & -15489.545 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{148.840} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.928 p = 0.698 q = 0.676  \newline{}(p1 = 0.072) w = 2.372 & -15415.125 &       &       &  \\
    \multirow{12}[0]{*}{\begin{sideways}Passeri 3 40\end{sideways}} & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{0.2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.106 q = 0.223} & -19091.743 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{610.258} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{7, 36, 40, 43, 46, 48, 49, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 61, 117, 125, 128, 131, 149, 152, 154, 158, 164, 179, 187, 230, 231, 238, 243, 255, 265}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.855 p = 0.679 q = 0.569\newline{}(p1 = 0.146) w = 2.593 & -18786.613 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.604 p = 1.530 q = 4.571 \newline{}(p1 = 0.396) w = 1.000 & -18950.591 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{327.956} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.855 p = 0.679 q = 0.569\newline{}(p1 = 0.146) w = 2.593 & -18786.613 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{2} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.576 q = 0.480} & -18987.839 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{402.451} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{7, 36, 40, 43, 46, 48, 49, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 61, 117, 125, 128, 131, 149, 152, 154, 158, 164, 179, 187, 230, 231, 238, 243, 255, 265}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.855 p = 0.679 q = 0.569\newline{}(p1 = 0.146) w = 2.593 & -18786.613 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.604 p = 1.530 q = 4.571\newline{}(p1 = 0.396) w = 1.000 & -18950.591 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{327.956} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.855 p = 0.679 q = 0.569\newline{}(p1 = 0.146) w = 2.593 & -18786.613 &       &       &  \\
          & \multirow{4}[0]{*}{5} & M7    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p = 0.094 q = 0.0676} & -19012.260 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{123.336} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{4}[0]{*}{7, 36, 40, 43, 46, 48, 49, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 61, 117, 125, 128, 131, 149, 152, 154, 158, 164, 179, 187, 230, 231, 238, 243, 255, 265}} \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.881 p = 0.663 q = 0.539\newline{}(p1 = 0.119) w = 2.727 & -18788.235 &       &       &  \\
          &       & M8a   & p0 = 0.604 p = 1.530 q = 4.571\newline{}(p1 = 0.39624) w = 1.000 & -18950.591 & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{324.714} & \multirow{2}[0]{*}{0.000} &  \\
          &       & M8    & p0 = 0.881 p = 0.663 q = 0.539\newline{}(p1 = 0.119) w = 2.727 & -18788.235 &       &       &  \\
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{longtable}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: please post the example in a form that people can test. It is currently missing `\documentclass` and uses a local `dissertation` package.  Do you really need so may rows of the table to show your issue?

Comment: From your code, you should receive an errormmessage along the lines of " Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.". To solve this, remoce `\centering` and add a `\\ ` after the `\caption` command.

Comment: Regarding your use of rotated text in multirow commands in teh first column. Please be warned that this approach might lead to undesired alignment effects with respect to the footer/page number. Probably it is better to entirely remove the firt column and to use `\multicolumn` commands instead (For a similar example see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/568292/134144)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just small cleanup of about half of your code fragment and little bit formatting of `\multirow` cells and removed all `\multicolumn` cells.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable,  makecell, multirow}

\begin{document}

\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.4pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}ccc l ccc 
                   >{\linespread{0.84}\selectfont\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{15em}
                  @{} }
    \toprule
  \caption{Add caption} \\
  \centering
\makecell{Data\\set} 
    & $\kappa$
        & Model 
            & \makecell{Parameters} 
                & \makecell{Likelihood\\ (lnL)} 
                    & \makecell{$2\Delta\ln L$\\ (LRT)} 
                        & \makecell{Significance\\ (p-value)} 
                            &  \makecell{PSS}                           \\
    \midrule
\multirow{21}[1]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Basal 40}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.616, q = 0.374 
                    & 4234.922
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{4.121}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{1.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{*}{---}                  \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.994,  p = 0.634 q = 0.421,\\ 
                               (p1 = 0.006), w = 2.742}
                    & 4236.983 &    &   &               \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.516, p = 32.811, q = 99.000,\\
                               (p1 = 0.484), w = 1.000} 
                    & 4232.605 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{8.755} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{1.000} &                  \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.994, p = 0.634, q = 0.421,\\
                               (p1 = 0.006), w = 2.742} 
                    & 4236.983 
                        &    &                                          \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.642, q = 0.412
                    & 4235.016 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{6.681} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.035} 
                                & \multirow{4}{*}{---}                  \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.748, p = 1.586, q = 2.192,\\
                               (p1 = 0.252), w = 1.475} 
                    & 4231.675
                        &   &                                           \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.516, p = 32.811, q = 99.000\\
                              (p1 =   0.4838), w = 1.000} 
                    & 4232.605
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{1.860}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.173}                    \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.748, p = 1.586, q = 2.19,2\\
                               (p1 = 0.252), w = 1.475}
                    & 4231.675 
                            &   &   &  \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p =   0.548 q =  0.314
                    & 4235.293 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{5.375}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.068} 
                                & \multirow{4}{*}{---}                  \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.859, p = 0.918, q = 0.804\\
                               (p1 = 0.141), w = 1.701} 
                    & 4232.419
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.516, p = 32.811, q = 99.000\\
                               (p1 = 0.484), w = 1.000}
                    & 4232.605
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{0.372}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.542}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.859, p = 0.918, q = 0.804,\\
                               (p1 = 0.141) w = 1.701} 
                    & 4232.419 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Strisores Aequorlitornithes 40}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.651, q = 0.345
                    & 5150.191 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{43.958} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{231, 276}             \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.755, p = 77.686, q = 99.000,\\
                               (p1 = 0.245), w = 1.968}
                    & 5128.212 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.528, p = 37.626, q = 99.000,\\
                                (p1 = 0.472), w = 1.000}
                    & 5141.065 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{25.706} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.755, p = 77.686, q = 99.000\\
                                (p1 = 0.245), w = 1.968}
                    & 5128.212 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2} 
        & M7    &  p = 0.651, q = 0.341
                    & 5147.952 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{34.978} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &  \multirow{4}{=}{48, 231, 276}        \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.851, p = 1.259, q = 0.934,\\
                                (p1 = 0.149), w = 2.375}
                    & 5130.463 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.535, p = 39.756, q = 99.000,\\
                                (p1 = 0.465), w = 1.000}
                    & 5141.103 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{21.279} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.851, p = 1.259, q = 0.934,\\
                                (p1 = 0.149), w = 2.375}
                    & 5130.463 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p = 0.722, q = 0.415
                    & 5147.937 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{13.745} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.001} 
                                & \multirow{4}{*}{231, 276}             \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.831, p = 1.645, q = 1.435,\\
                                (p1 = 0.169) w = 2.193}
                    & 5129.820 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.528, p = 37.626, q = 99.000,\\
                                (p1 = 0.472) w = 1.000}
                    & 5141.065
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{22.491}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.831, p = 1.645, q = 1.435,\\
                                (p1 = 0.169), w = 2.193} 
                    & 5129.820 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
\pagebreak  
    \midrule
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Acanthisittidae Tyranni Passeri 40}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.474, q = 0.321
            & -9711.558 
                & \multirow{2}{*}{234.997} 
                    & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                        & \multirow{4}{=}{33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275}                                      \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.799, p = 0.561, q = 0.446,\\
                               (p1 = 0.201), w = 2.790} 
                    & -9594.059 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.507, p = 2.450, q = 11.117,\\
                               (p1 = 0.494), w = 1.000}
                    & -9688.670 & 
                        \multirow{2}{*}{189.221} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &\makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.799, p = 0.561, q = 0.446,\\
                              (p1 = 0.201), w = 2.790}
                    & -9594.059 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2}
        & M7    & p = 0.480 q = 0.319
                    & -9711.442 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{234.203} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{14, 33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275} \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.800, p = 0.550, q = 0.435,\\
                               (p1 = 0.200) w = 2.762}
                    & -9594.340 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.507, p = 2.450, q = 11.120,\\
                               (p1 = 0.494) w = 1.000}
                    & -9688.670 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{188.659} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.800, p = 0.550, q = 0.435,\\
                               (p1 = 0.200) w = 2.762}
                    & -9594.340 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p = 0.187, q = 0.041
                    & -9713.369 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{237.519} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{14, 33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 113, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275}                     \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.811, p = 0.540, q = 0.444,\\
                               (p1 = 0.189), w = 2.768}
                    & -9594.610 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.507, p = 2.450, q = 11.117,\\
                           (p1 = 0.494), w = 1.000}
                    & -9688.670 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{188.120} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.811, p = 0.540, q = 0.444,\\
                               (p1 = 0.189), w = 2.768}
                    & -9594.610 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
\end{longtable}%
\end{document}
```

Other part of your table you can edit on the same way as I do in above MWE. However, before you start this, rething if it is worth. I will go by way as shown in @leandriis nice answer (+1).
Note,
`longtable` can break table only between rows. Since your multirow cells in the first column span 12 rows (with altogether 21 lines), it can be break it at some spanned row. This cause, that content of this cells is visible only on one page, protruding bottom of page. This can be prevent by manula breaking table before this cells or use `\\*` at all row except at beginning of multirow cells in the first column.

Above MWE produce the following table:

[image]

(red lines show page layout, present is part of table in the second page)

Comment: Hello, could you tell me which part of the code makes the horizontal words be centered? I'm making a similar code and I'd like to do that.

Comment: Which text? Rotated? For example in `\multirow{21}[1]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Basal 40}} ` number 21 define number of text lines in adjacent cells, number `[1]` shift (manaly set, after seeing position of text) when necessary. For more details, please see documentation for package `multirow`. No other text in provided solution is centered.

Comment: Helped a lot, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an attempt to redesign part of the table to avoid very wide columns and multirow:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{dissertation}
\usepackage{longtable, array, booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage{multirow,rotating}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}
\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{cclcccl}
  \caption{Add caption}\\
%  \centering
   \thead{kappa}
     & \thead{Model}
       & \thead{Parameters} 
         & \thead{Likelihood\\(lnL)} 
           & \thead{2∆lnL\\ (LRT)} 
             & \thead{Significance\\(p-value)} 
               & \thead{PSS} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Dataset: Basal 40}\\
    0.2 & M7  & p = 0.616  & 4234.922 & 4.121 & 1.000 & - \\
        &     & q = 0.374                                 \\
        & M8  & p0 = 0.994 & 4236.983 &       &       &   \\
        &     & p = 0.634                                 \\
        &     & q = 0.421                                 \\
        &     & (p1 =   0.006)                            \\
        &     &  w = 2.742                                \\
        & M8a & p0 = 0.516  & 4232.605 & 8.755 & 1.000 &  \\
        &     & p = 32.811                                \\
        &     & q = 99.000                                \\
        &     & (p1 = 0.484)                              \\
        &     &  w = 1.000                                \\
        & M8  & p0 = 0.994  & 4236.983 &       &       &  \\
        &     & p = 0.634                                 \\
        &     & q = 0.421                                 \\
        &     & (p1 = 0.006)                              \\
        &     & w = 2.742                                 \\
        \midrule
        \multicolumn{7}{@{}l}{Dataset: Strisores Aequorlitornithes 40}\\
        
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{longtable}%

\end{document}
```