# Can't align tables

Tags: longtable, xltabular

[image: This is the image where the table is aligned]In my supplemental material, I have some tables such as this one.
[image: This is the xtabular which is not aligned]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable,  makecell, multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize}

\small
\setlength\tabcolsep{2.4pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{}ccc l ccc 
                   >{\linespread{0.84}\selectfont\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{15em}
                  @{} }
  \caption{\gls{paml} results for site model comparisons for test of positive selection of the \gls{Tas2r}40 datasets} \\
    \toprule
  \centering
\makecell{Dataset} 
    & $\kappa$
        & Model 
            & \makecell{Parameters} 
                & \makecell{Likelihood\\ (lnL)} 
                    & \makecell{$2\Delta\ln L$\\ (LRT)} 
                        & \makecell{Significance\\ (p-value)} 
                            &  \makecell{PSS}                           \\
    \midrule
\multirow{21}[1]{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{Basal\_40}}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.616, q = 0.374 
                    & -4234.922
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{-4.121}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{1.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{*}{---}                  \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.994,  p = 0.634 q = 0.421\\ 
                               (p1 = 0.006), w = 2.742}
                    & -4236.983 &    &   &               \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.516, p = 32.811, q = 99.000\\
                               (p1 = 0.484), w = 1.000} 
                    & -4232.605 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{-8.755} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{1.000} &                  \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.994, p = 0.634, q = 0.421\\
                               (p1 = 0.006), w = 2.742} 
                    & -4236.983 
                        &    &                                          \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.642, q = 0.412
                    & -4235.016 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{6.681} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.035} 
                                & \multirow{4}{*}{---}                  \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.748, p = 1.586, q = 2.192\\
                               (p1 = 0.252), w = 1.475} 
                    & -4231.675
                        &   &                                           \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.516, p = 32.811, q = 99.000\\
                              (p1 =   0.4838), w = 1.000} 
                    & -4232.605
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{1.860}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.173}                    \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.748, p = 1.586, q = 2.192\\
                               (p1 = 0.252), w = 1.475}
                    & -4231.675 
                            &   &   &  \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p = 0.548 q = 0.314
                    & -4235.293 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{5.375}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.068} 
                                & \multirow{4}{*}{---}                  \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.859, p = 0.918, q = 0.804\\
                               (p1 = 0.141), w = 1.701} 
                    & -4232.419
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.516, p = 32.811, q = 99.000\\
                               (p1 = 0.484), w = 1.000}
                    & -4232.605
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{0.372}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.542}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.859, p = 0.918, q = 0.804\\
                               (p1 = 0.141) w = 1.701} 
                    & -4232.419 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{Strisores\_Aequorlitornithes\_40}}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.651, q = 0.345
                    & -5150.191 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{43.958} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{231, 276}             \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.755, p = 77.686, q = 99.000\\
                               (p1 = 0.245), w = 1.968}
                    & -5128.212 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.528, p = 37.626, q = 99.000\\
                                (p1 = 0.472), w = 1.000}
                    & -5141.065 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{25.706} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.755, p = 77.686, q = 99.000\\
                                (p1 = 0.245), w = 1.968}
                    & -5128.212 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2} 
        & M7    &  p = 0.651, q = 0.341
                    & -5147.952 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{34.978} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &  \multirow{4}{=}{48, 231, 276}        \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.851, p = 1.259, q = 0.934\\
                                (p1 = 0.149), w = 2.375}
                    & -5130.463 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.535, p = 39.756, q = 99.000\\
                                (p1 = 0.465), w = 1.000}
                    & -5141.103 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{21.279} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.851, p = 1.259, q = 0.934\\
                                (p1 = 0.149), w = 2.375}
                    & -5130.463 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p = 0.722, q = 0.415
                    & -5147.937 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{13.745} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.001} 
                                & \multirow{4}{*}{231, 276}             \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.831, p = 1.645, q = 1.435\\
                                (p1 = 0.169) w = 2.193}
                    & -5129.820 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.528, p = 37.626, q = 99.000\\
                                (p1 = 0.472) w = 1.000}
                    & -5141.065
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{22.491}
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &  \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.831, p = 1.645, q = 1.435\\
                                (p1 = 0.169), w = 2.193} 
                    & -5129.820 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{Acanthisittidae\_Tyranni\_Passeri\_40}}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.474, q = 0.321
            & -9711.558 
                & \multirow{2}{*}{234.997} 
                    & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                        & \multirow{4}{=}{33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275}                                      \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.799, p = 0.561, q = 0.446\\
                               (p1 = 0.201), w = 2.790} 
                    & -9594.059 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.507, p = 2.450, q = 11.117\\
                               (p1 = 0.494), w = 1.000}
                    & -9688.670 & 
                        \multirow{2}{*}{189.221} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &\makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.799, p = 0.561, q = 0.446\\
                              (p1 = 0.201), w = 2.790}
                    & -9594.059 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2}
        & M7    & p = 0.480 q = 0.319
                    & -9711.442 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{234.203} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{14, 33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275} \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.800, p = 0.550, q = 0.435\\
                               (p1 = 0.200) w = 2.762}
                    & -9594.340 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.507, p = 2.450, q = 11.120\\
                               (p1 = 0.494) w = 1.000}
                    & -9688.670 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{188.659} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.800, p = 0.550, q = 0.435\\
                               (p1 = 0.200) w = 2.762}
                    & -9594.340 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p = 0.187, q = 0.041
                    & -9713.369 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{237.519} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{14, 33 , 36 , 37 , 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 51, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 67, 69, 111, 113, 116, 122, 124, 125, 127, 128, 130, 153, 157, 164, 179, 228, 229, 230, 231, 233, 234, 237, 238, 241, 243, 265, 275}                     \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.811, p = 0.540, q = 0.444\\
                               (p1 = 0.189), w = 2.768}
                    & -9594.610 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.507, p = 2.450, q = 11.117\\
                           (p1 = 0.494), w = 1.000}
                    & -9688.670 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{188.120} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.811, p = 0.540, q = 0.444\\
                               (p1 = 0.189), w = 2.768}
                    & -9594.610 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{Passeri\_1\_40}}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.421 q = 0.386
            & -11405.799 
                & \multirow{2}{*}{256.626} 
                    & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                        & \multirow{4}{=}{6, 7, 20, 33, 36, 40, 41, 43, 46, 48, 49, 50, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 64, 70, 112, 114, 125, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 151, 152, 158, 160, 161, 163, 164, 165, 180, 184, 188, 190, 205, 206, 220, 231, 232, 235, 238, 239, 242, 244, 245, 246, 252, 256, 266, 277, 279}                                      \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.745 p = 0.872 q = 1.130\\
                               (p1 = 0.255) w = 2.364} 
                    & -11277.486 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.598 p = 2.219 q = 8.395\\
                               (p1 = 0.402) w = 1.000}
                    & -11373.833 & 
                        \multirow{2}{*}{192.695} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &\makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.745 p = 0.872 q = 1.130\\
                              (p1 = 0.255) w = 2.364}
                    & -11277.486 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2}
        & M7    & p = 0.469 q = 0.411
                    & -11405.085 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{253.680} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{6, 7, 20, 33, 36, 40, 41, 43, 46, 48, 49, 50, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 64, 70, 112, 114, 125, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 151, 152, 158, 160, 161, 163, 164, 165, 180, 184, 188, 190, 205, 206, 220, 231, 232, 235, 238, 239, 242, 244, 245, 246, 252, 256, 266, 277, 279} \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.767 p = 0.860 q = 1.137\\
                               (p1 = 0.233) w = 2.325}
                    & -11278.245 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.598 p = 2.219 q = 8.395\\
                               (p1 = 0.402) w = 1.000}
                    & -11373.833 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{191.177} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.767 p = 0.860 q = 1.137\\
                               (p1 = 0.233) w = 2.325}
                    & -11278.245 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p = 0.437 q = 0.387
                    & -11405.189 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{62.711} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{6, 7, 20, 33, 36, 40, 41, 43, 46, 48, 49, 50, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 60, 61, 64, 70, 112, 114, 125, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 151, 152, 158, 160, 161, 163, 164, 165, 180, 184, 188, 190, 205, 206, 220, 231, 232, 235, 238, 239, 242, 244, 245, 246, 252, 256, 266, 277, 279}                     \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.777 p = 0.839 q = 1.090\\
                               (p1 = 0.223) w = 2.389}
                    & -11278.856 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.598 p = 2.219 q = 8.395\\
                           (p1 = 0.402) w = 1.000}
                    & -11373.833 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{189.954} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.777 p = 0.839 q = 1.090\\
                               (p1 = 0.223) w = 2.389}
                    & -11278.856 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{Passeri\_2\_40}}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.581 q = 0.493
            & -15508.558 
                & \multirow{2}{*}{192.533} 
                    & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                        & \multirow{4}{=}{7, 11, 70, 117, 126, 128, 131, 154, 160, 165, 180, 188, 220, 235, 239, 266, 275, 279}                                      \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.920 p = 0.669 q = 0.610\\
                               (p1 = 0.080) w = 2.609} 
                    & -15412.292 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.667 p = 1.297 q = 3.397\\
                               (p1 = 0.333) w = 1.000}
                    & -15489.545 & 
                        \multirow{2}{*}{154.507} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &\makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.920 p = 0.669 q = 0.610\\
                              (p1 = 0.080) w = 2.609}
                    & -15412.292 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2}
        & M7    & p = 0.545 q = 0.489
                    & -15509.467 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{194.352} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{7, 11, 70, 117, 126, 128, 131, 154, 160, 165, 180, 188, 220, 235, 239, 266, 275, 279} \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.920 p = 0.669 q = 0.610\\
                               (p1 = 0.080) w = 2.609}
                    & -15412.292 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.667 p = 1.297 q = 3.397\\
                               (p1 = 0.333) w = 1.000}
                    & -15489.545 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{154.507} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.920 p = 0.669 q = 0.610\\
                               (p1 = 0.080) w = 2.609}
                    & -15412.292 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p = 0.551 q = 0.465
                    & -15509.257 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{39.424} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{7, 11, 70, 117, 126, 128, 131, 154, 160, 165, 166, 180, 188, 220, 235, 239, 266, 275, 279}                     \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.928 p = 0.698 q = 0.676\\
                               (p1 = 0.072) w = 2.372}
                    & -15415.125 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.667 p = 1.297 q = 3.396\\
                           (p1 = 0.333) w = 1.000}
                    & -15489.545
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{148.840} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.928 p = 0.698 q = 0.676\\
                               (p1 = 0.072) w = 2.372}
                    & -15415.125 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
\multirow{21}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{\texttt{Passeri\_3\_40}}} 
    & \multirow{4}{*}{0.2} 
        & M7    & p = 0.106 q = 0.223
            & -19091.743 
                & \multirow{2}{*}{610.258} 
                    & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                        & \multirow{4}{=}{7, 36, 40, 43, 46, 48, 49, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 61, 117, 125, 128, 131, 149, 152, 154, 158, 164, 179, 187, 230, 231, 238, 243, 255, 265}                                      \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.855 p = 0.679 q = 0.569\\
                               (p1 = 0.146) w = 2.593} 
                    & -18786.613 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.604 p = 1.530 q = 4.571\\
                               (p1 = 0.396) w = 1.000}
                    & -18950.591 & 
                        \multirow{2}{*}{327.956} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    &\makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.855 p = 0.679 q = 0.569\\
                              (p1 = 0.146) w = 2.593}
                    & -18786.613 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{2}
        & M7    & p = 0.576 q = 0.480
                    & -18987.839 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{402.451} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{7, 36, 40, 43, 46, 48, 49, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 61, 117, 125, 128, 131, 149, 152, 154, 158, 164, 179, 187, 230, 231, 238, 243, 255, 265} \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.855 p = 0.679 q = 0.569\\
                               (p1 = 0.146) w = 2.593}
                    & -18786.613 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.604 p = 1.530 q = 4.571\\
                               (p1 = 0.396) w = 1.000}
                    & -18950.591 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{327.956} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.855 p = 0.679 q = 0.569\\
                               (p1 = 0.146) w = 2.593}
                    & -18786.613 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule{2-8}
    & \multirow{4}{*}{5} 
        & M7    & p = 0.094 q = 0.068
                    & -19012.260 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{123.336} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000} 
                                & \multirow{4}{=}{7, 36, 40, 43, 46, 48, 49, 52, 55, 56, 57, 59, 61, 117, 125, 128, 131, 149, 152, 154, 158, 164, 179, 187, 230, 231, 238, 243, 255, 265}                     \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.881 p = 0.663 q = 0.539\\
                               (p1 = 0.119) w = 2.727}
                    & -18788.235 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    &   & M8a   & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.604 p = 1.530 q = 4.571\\
                           (p1 = 0.396) w = 1.000}
                    & -18950.591 
                        & \multirow{2}{*}{324.714} 
                            & \multirow{2}{*}{0.000}
                                &                                       \\
    &   & M8    & \makecell[l]{ p0 = 0.881 p = 0.663 q = 0.539\\
                               (p1 = 0.119) w = 2.727}
                    & -18788.235 
                        &   &   &                                       \\
    \midrule
  \label{table:Supplemental Table 9}%
\end{longtable}%
```

Then when I put the one that it's beneath I couldn't align it with the other ones. I needed to push it more to the right. Does someone know how I could do it? I added an image to show what the output looks like.

```
\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10pt}
\centering
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{c l X X X X}
  \caption{\gls{dm} (\gls{slac}, \gls{meme}, \gls{fel}, \gls{fubar}) results for site model comparisons for test of positive selection of the \gls{Tas2r}9 datasets.} \\  
    \toprule
    \thead{Dataset} &  & \thead{SLAC} & \thead{MEME}  & \thead{FEL}   & \thead{FUBAR} \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{6}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Basal\_9}}} & number of PSS &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{11} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{2} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites & 175, 184 & 7, 15, 71, 75, 81, 144, 164, 169, 175, 179, 181, 182, 184, 258, 288 & 71, 81, 88, 143, 144, 164, 175, 181, 182, 184, 258 & 81, 184 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{5}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Strisores\_Aequorlitornithes\_9}}} & number of PSS &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{19} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{14} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{3} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites & 71, 165, 176, 194, 261 & 18, 30, 59, 70, 71, 75, 76, 80, 86, 90, 95, 104, 165, 176, 194, 204, 222, 261, 272 & 18, 70, 71, 76, 86, 90, 165, 176, 194, 204, 218, 254, 261, 272 & 71, 86, 261 \\
                        &   &   &                                        \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{8}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Piciformes\_9}}} & number of PSS &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{5} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{24} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{15} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{4} \\
\cmidrule{2-6}          & sites & 92, 94, 168, 254, 270 & 14, 23, 50, 55, 62, 67, 71, 73, 74, 82, 92, 94, 98, 120, 143, 168, 173, 236, 254, 263, 270, 294, 295, 302 & 23, 55, 59, 73, 92, 94, 143, 168, 188, 254, 257, 263, 270, 294, 302 & 94, 168, 254, 263 \\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{11}{*}{\rotatebox{90}{Acanthisittidae\_Tyranni\_Passeri\_1\_9}}} & number of PSS &  \multicolumn{1}{c}{27} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{35} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{27} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{24} \\
    \midrule                    
  \label{table:Supplemental Table 9}%
\end{xltabular}
```

Comment: it would be much easier to help if you provided code that showed the problem, can you not edit the example to use a standard class and remove all packages not used in the example, so people can see the issue. Currently we can not run the code so you are asking us to guess what the output looks like and guess how you want to change it

Comment: I edited my code, however, I can't replicate what happens in my document because in this new document it's the first table that is too far to the right, while in my original document is the second table that is not aligned. Basically, I wanted to know is there is some command I can use instead of \textwidth that allows me to move the table a bit to the right. Thanks and I'm sorry for not being clear

Comment: it's very hard to guess the issue if we can't run the code and you don't even show an image of the output.  Looking at the code the second table is forced to be textwidth wide, the first (longtable) one is set natural width and centred. There is no alignment between the two specified and (despite it being my code mostly) I really can't guess what the output looks like or what alignment you want.

Comment: You already ask similar question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568834/column-on-longtable-doesnt-show-up)  which answer <ou accepted. What is now different in comparison to this answer? Why now you not use solution in accepted answer?

Comment: I added an image so I can show what the output looks like.

Comment: That table works great. I added a new table and that one, even though has \textwidth on it, is very close to the left margin, which is not aligned with the rest of my centered tables so I wondered if someone could help me with that issue.

Comment: Go to your original document, add \usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}} to the preamble and compile two to three times. Please take a screenshot of one of the pages with a correctly centered table as well as a screenshot of one of the pages with the xltabular on it and add thouse screenshots to your question.

Comment: @Zarko no because my problem is with xtabular

Comment: @RaquelCardoso, in question you not mentioned, that you have a problem with it ... Your question is not only duplicate (you already have a solution for your problem, see your quastion https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568834/column-on-longtable-doesnt-show-up) but also unclear.

Comment: @Zarko how is that a solution to my problem if my new table xtabular is the one I can't align with the rest?

Comment: @leandriis I added the images now. I think now it's possible to see that the xtabular is not aligned with the red lines and that's why I need to move it a bit to the right. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @RaquelCardoso, please show us this. This cannot happen when you use `xltabular` (properly). However it is case when you use `longatle` and not defined columns types properly.

Comment: How you what? Yes, I know that it shouldn't happen because I tried in a new document and the xtabular worked fine. However, this xtabular is part of my Master thesis so I just need to find a way to fix it somehow

Comment: @RaquelCardoso: Thanks a lot for the screenshot. This is definitely interesting and I suppose something unusual and yet not shown in your question is going on in your document since the `longtable` itself is already placed differently than expected. [...]

Comment: [...] Did you use `\setlength\LTleft` somewhere in your document to make overly wide `longtable`s "centered"  on the page while letting them protrude into both margins? If so, this command is the reason for the observed "misalignment". Either remove it and make sure the tables are narrow enough to fit into the available space (e.g. by also using `xltabular` for them) or just use it locally/reset it to `0pt` right before the start of the `xltabular`.

Comment: That totally solved my problem, thank you @leandriis!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you added to your question clearly shows a non standard behaviour of the `longtable`. Since it is definitely wider than the textwidth, I would expect it to start at the first vertical red line and protrude quite significantly into the right margin. Since this is not the case here, you must have used `\setlength\LTleft{...}` somewhere in your document to make your overly wide longtable(s) "centered" on the page while letting it/them protrude into both margins. This setting also influences the position of the following `xltabular` and is thus the reason for the observed "misalignment".

To overcome this, you have the following options:

1. Remove `\setlength\LTleft{...}`, and rewrite your `longtable`(s) to `xltabular`(s)  in order to make sure all tables fit into the textwidth.
2. Remove `\setlength\LTleft{...}`, and decrease the (left and right) margin sizes for your appendix (?) and make sure the textwidth is now wider or just as wide as your widest `longtable`.
3. Use `\setlength\LTleft{...}` only locally for the `longtable`(s) or reset it to `\setlength\LTleft{...}` right before the start of the `xltabular`.

(Options are listed in order of my personal preference.)

Answer (score 1):

No really an answer, but a try to clarifying misunderstandings:

- You use `article` document class with default page layout, which `\textwidth` is for your table (far) to small
- Answer, which I provide you on your [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/568834/column-on-longtable-doesnt-show-up),
  use `book` document class and has page layout defined by `geometry` package:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
```

- If you will add to your MWE `\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}`, than your table will nicely placed on your table.
- If this is not an allowed option, then you have to rethink about table layout. About this, the following cross my mind:

  - rotate table, i.e. set it in `landscape` orientation
  - the first column replace with row, and fourth column make narrower  with list cells contents for example as

```
\multicolumn{7}{l}{\texttt{Basal\_40}}                          \\
    \addlinespace
0.2 & M7 & \makecell[lt]{p = 0.616,\\ 
                         q = 0.374}
            & -4234.922
                & \multirow{2}{*}{-4.121}
                    & \multirow{2}{*}{1.000}
                        & \multirow{4}{=}{---}                  \\
```

- In the both cases I would use `xltabular` instead of `longtable`. Using it is simpler adopt table width to `\textwidth`. For example:

```
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{}   ccc l ccc
{\linespread{0.84}\selectfont\raggedright\arraybackslash}X  % <---
                            @{} }
    \caption{\gls{paml} results for site model comparisons for test of positive selection of the \gls{Tas2r}40 datasets}
    \label{table:Supplemental Table 9}  \\
```

Now is up to you, what you more prefer. At this, please be aware, that it is extremely difficult to put elephant into lady suitcase ...

Comment: Thank you but I rest the \setlength\LTleft{-1.8cm} to 0 before xtabular and it worked